# Create a Catch-All Handler in PHP?

Tags: php, url, redirect, catch-all

I want to have a PHP file catch and manage what's going to happen when users visit:

*http://profiles.mywebsite.com/**sometext***

**sometext** is varying.

E.g. It can be **someuser** it can be **john**, etc. then I want a PHP file to handle requests from that structure.

My main goal is to have that certain PHP file to redirect my site users to their corresponding profiles but their profiles are different from that URL structure. I'm aiming for giving my users a sort of easy-to-remember profile URLs.

Thanks to those who'd answer!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Either in Apache configuration files [VirtualHost or Directory directives], or in .htaccess file put following line:

```
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

It will silently redirect all incoming requests that do not correspond to valid filename or directory (`RewriteCond`'s in the code above make sure of that), to index.php file. Additionally, as you see, `MultiViews` option also needs to be disabled for redirection to work - it generally conflicts with these two `RewriteCond`'s I put there.

Inside index.php you can access the `REQUEST_URI` data via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable. You shouldn't pass any URIs via `GET`, as it may pollute your Query-String data in an undesired way, since `[QSA]` parameter in our RewriteRule is active.

Comment: Thanks! I'm off to try this out! :) Umm, do URL shortening websites use this approach as well?

Comment: No :) That is a different topic.

Comment: Ohh okay, will post about that sometime in the future but for now, this should do. :)

Answer (score 5):

You should use a rewrite rule..

In apache (.htaccess), something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then in your index.php you can read $_GET['url'] in your php code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a .htaccess file (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html) to rewrite your url to something like profiles.websites.com/index.php?page=sometext . Then you can do what you want with sometext in index.php.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious way to do this would be via the 404 errorDocument - saves all that messing about with mod_rewrite.

Comment: Search engines may not index the pages if the server sends a 404 response code. So be sure to send an 200 (OK) response code if you use this method.

Answer (score -6):

If you have not heard about MVC, its time you hear it, start with CodeIgniter, its simplest and is quite fast, use default controller and you can have URLs like
`domain.com/usernam/profile`
`domain.com/usernam/profile/edit`
`domain.com/usernam/inbox`
`domain.com/usernam/inbox/read/messageid` Or use .htaccess wisely