# Is it possible to make one PHP file to handle all requests coming to server public folder?

Tags: php

If I have site www.mysite.com and then I have folder apache/htdocs as public folder in my server. I would like to have all requests made to www.mysite.com be assigned to index.php file. Is that possble or do I have to have folders if I want to have urls like www.mysite.com/about/ ? And how can I access path information in PHP code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a Catch-All Handler in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218213/create-a-catch-all-handler-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mod_rewrite`.

See http://www.workingwith.me.uk/blog/software/open_source/apache/mod_rewriting_an_entire_site  for a complete example.

This should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

no you use something called mod_rewrite to achieve the desired effect,
there is diffrent regex depending on how your requests look like
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

what it does is basically if you have a url that looks like this
url.com/index.php?page=about
make it look like 
url.com/about/
but backend the request is just the same
you could make it work anyway u want depends on the rules you apply to your mod_rewrite